# バッチファイルを実行するとき、勝手に管理者権限になってしまう

Tags: windows, batch-file

Windows 7 を使っています。

バッチファイルをダブルクリックするなどして実行するときに、勝手に管理者権限で実行されてしまうような挙動をしています。

検証のため、[How to check in a batch file if you are running it elevated](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-check-in-a-batch-file-if-you-are-running-it-elevated/) に記述されているような、バッチファイルを、次の手順で作成・実行しました。

1. デスクトップを右クリック、新規作成 -> テキストファイル
2. メモ帳で開き、管理者権限判定用のバッチファイルを(コピーアンドペーストで)記述、適当な .bat ファイルへリネーム
3. ダブルクリックで実行

結果、管理者権限で実行されている、という表示は出るのですが、これは望んでいる結果ではなく、普通に実行したときには、一般権限で実行してほしい、と考えています。

何が原因でこのような動作になっていると考えられるでしょうか。

Comment: 具体的にどういうバッチファイルを記述したのでしょうか。リンク先の内容そのままですか？単に`openfiles`のみを実行するバッチファイルを実行するとどうなりますか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[UAC; ユーザーアカウント制御はオンに](http://windows.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/turn-user-account-control-on-off#1TC=windows-7)なっているのでしょうか？ またオンであってもアカウントが `Administrator` の場合は管理者権限で実行されますので他のアカウントを使用する必要があります。

Comment: on にするだけで、普通に実行しただけでは elevate されなくなりました。(Administrator ユーザーですが、期待する動作を得ました)

Comment: @YukiInoue 管理者権限（**Administrators**グループのメンバー）という意味ではなく、ビルトインユーザー（ユーザー名 **Administrator**、既定では無効化されている）のことを指しました。

Answer (score 1):

ユーザーアカウント制御はONの状態が望ましいとは思いますが、 runasを使うのはどうでしょう？
/userで一般ユーザーを指定して/savecredでパスワードを保存すれば今までの環境で一般ユーザーでの起動ができると思います。
http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/0606/17/news015.html